# Woopse No preview available google doc

Tags: android, google-docs, google-document-viewer

I am using google doc link for showing pdf in android app.But for few files a message appear "Woops no preview aviable".
I uploaded same file on dropbox and use that link its working fine.
What could be the issue

Comment: what URL you are using ? can you provide doc. URL

Comment: https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=https: